# Rails, how to access the belongs_to (parent) object, through child object in the shallow-nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, belongs-to, nested-resources

So, first of all I have this association going on in my project:

routes.rb

```
resources :users do  
  resources :articles, only: [:new, :index, :create]
end  

resources :articles, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] do 
  resrouces :comments 
end
```

article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :user
    validates :title, presence: true,
                  length: { minimum: 5 }

    validates :text, presence: true,
                 length: { in: 1..200 }
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
    other codes..
end
```

So basically a shallow nested resource. The problem I have with is that in my articles_controller.rb:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @articles = Article.all
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) #This works fine.
    end

    def new
        @article = Article.new
        @user = @User.find(params[user_id])  #This works fine.
    end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) #@user = nil, because show action is not in the nested resource, thus :user_id is not available??
        @user = @article.user  #@user = nil, again....
    end

    other codes...
end
```

I need @user variable in my show.html.erb, for various reasons including linking back to the user's articles' index page.

Is there any way I can retrieve the @user object through @article object???

I have been searching solutions for this problem, but there doesn't seem to be an obvious one... Can anyone please help me with this situation without having to break the shallow-nested resources?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is your second attempt. If `@article.user` is `nil`, it is because `@article` has no `user`.

Make sure that the article you are showing has an user.

Can be a good option add this presence validation to `Article` class:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  validates :user, presence: true
  #...
end
```

Comment: Even with that validattion line, my article doesn't seem to have user access .... T.T

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed the problem by adding a line --> @article.user = @user on my create action.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def index
    @articles = Article.all
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end

def new
    @article = Article.new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end

def create
    @article = Article.new(allow_params)
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @article.user = @user
    if @article.save
        flash[:notice] = "You have successfully saved."

        redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
        render new_user_article_path(@user)
    end
end
```

and whenever I needed @user,  I just accessed it through @article.user